# What's the best VS 2013 project template for a non-.NET Azure Web Site?

Tags: iis, azure, visual-studio-2013

I've created a website using Azure Web Sites. It is using IIS, Drupal, MySQL. So far so good. Now I want to create a Visual Studio 2013 project that will contain my web site files, including CSS via the LESS preprocessor, theme files, JavaScript files, etc. I'm thinking of using WebDeploy but might also use FTP to make it easier for non-Windows workers to do uploads. I have no plans to use .NET in this website. I have installed the Azure SDK 2.5.

I have read the page on why web app projects are better than website projects. So my question is which project template is best to use for web applications? All of them seem to assume one is using .NET. I can ignore that but I would still get a bunch of .NET variables and files.

Comment: You can always delete things after the project is created. Like, delete all the references.

Comment: Yes, that occurred to me. It is just hard to know exactly what can be deleted and what can't. Another way to go might be to use a project template from a non-.NET VS add-in like PTVS (Python Tools for VS). I'm guessing its templates don't contain the .NET stuff but it leaves me deleting Python stuff instead.

Comment: Once you get an empty project that works for you, you can save it as a template, using File->Export Template.